# What is the complete reaction for Cyanide ions reacting with Thiosulfate?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, redox, ions

I was recently studying about the properties of Sodium Thiosulfate, where I came across the fact that $\ce{S2O3^2-}$ reacts with $\ce{CN-}$ ions to produce $\ce{SCN-}$ ions. This was quite useful in treating cyanide poisoning.

I have tried to find the complete reaction, but with no success. I believe this must be a redox reaction, since $\ce{S2O3^2-}$ has an average oxidation state of $+2$, while $\ce{SCN-}$ has a state of $-2$ (correct me if this is wrong). Can someone give me the complete reaction?

Comment: Redox reactions can be very complicated. In this case there's probably no complete scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Source 1](https://www.chemicalaid.com/tools/equationbalancer.php?equation=Na2S2O3%20%2B%20NaCN%20%3D%20Na2SO3%20%2B%20NaSCN)(If you consider $\ce{Na+}$ as counterions)

$$\ce{Na2S2O3 + NaCN -> Na2SO3 + NaSCN}$$

> Sodium thiosulfate reacts with sodium cyanide to produce sodium
>   sulfite and sodium thiocyanate.

2. [Source 2](http://chemiday.com/en/reaction/3-1-0-2133)(If you consider $\ce{Ag+}$ and $\ce{Na+}$ as counterions for cyanide and thiosulfate ion respectively)

$$\ce{AgCN + 2Na2S2O3 → Na3[Ag(S2O3)2] + NaCN}$$

> Silver(I) cyanide react with sodium thiosulfate to produce sodium
>   dithiosulfatoargentate(I) and sodium cyanide.

In this case, thiocyanate does not form, rather a complex forms.

Explanation of this reaction can be found by observing the related reactions given in the [Wikipedia article of sodium thiosulfate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_thiosulfate).

> Silver halides, e.g., AgBr are typical components of photographic
>   emulsions, dissolve upon treatment with aqueous thiosulfate:
>
> $$\ce{2S2O3^{2−} + AgBr → [Ag(S2O3)2]^{3−} + Br^{−}}$$

Since, $\ce{CN-}$  and $\ce{Br-}$ hold same charge,  you can easily replace it with silver bromide with silver cyanide  to get  cyanide ions as products.

Furthermore:

> Sodium thiosulfate is a component of an
>   alternative lixiviant to cyanide for extraction of gold to form a
>   strong soluble complex $\ce{[Au(S2O3)2]^{3−}}$. The advantage of this
>   approach is that thiosulfate is essentially not toxic and that ore
>   types that are refractory to gold
>   cyanidation (e.g. carbonaceous or Carlin-type ores) can be leached by
>   thiosulfate. Some problems  include the high consumption of
>   thiosulfate, and the lack of a suitable recovery technique, since
>   $\ce{[Au(S2O3)2]^{3−}}$ does not adsorb to activated carbon, which is
>   the standard technique used in gold cyanidation to separate the gold
>   complex from the ore slurry.

This process is also suitable for silver extraction using sodium thiosulfate and silver cyanide to form corresponding silver complex, $\ce{[Ag(S2O3)2]^{3-}}$. Just replace gold cyanide with silver cyanide and it will work pretty much well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please guide me to sources that explain the reactions of thiosulfate, particularly silver thiosulfate?

Comment: @PrittBalagopal Thanks for the feedback. I edited the answer to make it clear